# Does Castle.Windsor allow Dependency Inversion Principle?

Tags: castle-windsor

We're trying to stick to DIP in our C# application, which means a higher level class in one project depends on an interface that is in the same project, and that interface is implemented by a lower level class in another project. The lower level project naturally depends on the higher level one.

This way, the higher level project can happily work with the interface without any knowledge or dependency on its implementation. But now I would like to run Windsor installers to register my needed dependencies top down, so my main class wants to register the implementations of the interfaces it uses, while it doesn't know(have dependency/project reference) them. I need to somehow run installers in projects without depending on them. I was hoping Castle had a way of "finding" those implementations and doing this for me cleanly, but it's probably not possible, is it?

I ended up running the installer in every assembly in the same directory as my main assembly, which works and is simple enough. It just doesn't feel clean... I wish there was a way of just asking for the implementation on my interface without depending on that project...

Comment: Are you just looking for `Classes.FromAssemblyNamed("ImplementationAssemblyName").BasedOn<IYourInterface>()`?

Comment: That still requires me to know the implementing assembly, at least by name. I was hoping that the higher level assembly would need no knowledge of the lower level one, that is implementing the interface. But there is no way around that, I guess... This works well enough:

Container.Install(FromAssembly.InDirectory(new AssemblyFilter(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location))));